# Assign value to an item of the list in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to change one value in the dict of list, but the values with the same index of lists in the dictionary all change. I played around with it in terminal, and you can see two different displays with the same assigning way.
https://ibb.co/fjWCCd

Sorry, I am not allowed to embed images yet. Or you can have a look down here

```
dict = {1:[0.0,0.0],2:[0.0,0.0]}
dict[1]
```

> [0.0, 0.0]

```
dict[1][0]
```

> 0.0

```
dict[1][0]+=1
dict
```

> {1: [1.0, 0.0], 2: [0.0, 0.0]}

```
dict[2][0] = 7
dict
```

> {1: [1.0, 0.0], 2: [7, 0.0]}

```
dict[2][1] = 3
dict
```

> {1: [1.0, 0.0], 2: [7, 3]}

```
std_log = [0.0,0.0]
thedict = {}
for i in range(8):
    thedict[i+1] = std_log
thedict
```

> {1: [0.0, 0.0], 2: [0.0, 0.0], 3: [0.0, 0.0], 4: [0.0, 0.0], 5: [0.0, 0.0], 6: [0.0, 0.0], 7: [0.0, 0.0], 8: [0.0, 0.0]}

```
thedict[2][1] = 6
thedict
```

> {1: [0.0, 6], 2: [0.0, 6], 3: [0.0, 6], 4: [0.0, 6], 5: [0.0, 6], 6: [0.0, 6], 7: [0.0, 6], 8: [0.0, 6]}

```
newvalue = thedict[2]
newvalue
```

> [0.0, 6]

```
newvalue[1]
```

> 6

```
newvalue[1] +=1
newvalue
```

> [0.0, 7]

```
thedict[2] = newvalue
thedict
```

> {1: [0.0, 7], 2: [0.0, 7], 3: [0.0, 7], 4: [0.0, 7], 5: [0.0, 7], 6: [0.0, 7], 7: [0.0, 7], 8: [0.0, 7]}

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Even if you could, it's not good to post images on stack-overflow

Comment: @U8-Forward if you want edit this post make sure you can still differentiate between commands (with $ sign) and return values (without $ sign)...

Comment: @HuyHNguyen Next question please make sure you edit your question correctly. Better use a code editor rather than the console for that matter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std_log = [0.0,0.0]
for i in range(8):
    thedict[i+1] = std_log
```

This creates a dict where all keys are associated to the same list `std_log`, so of course modifying one (key,value) pair will affect all other values (since they are the same object). Do this instead:

```
thedict = {i+1: [0.0,0.0] for i in range(8)}
```

This will create new lists for every single key, and you'll be able to modify them independently.

Comment: Thanks, Julien. Your suggestion solves the problem. So std_log is the common point if I do such assignment. I'm curious that, in this case, std_log is just a small list, then we can type the [0.0,0.0] .But, what if std_log is a huge list, then how we can assign std_log without issues about common reference?

Comment: If `std_log` is a big list (result from another routine?) you can still use copies of it: `thedict = {i+1: std_log[:] for i in range(8)}`. `[:]` effectively creates a copy. But beware it may not work with other structures, e.g. numpy arrays. Using `.copy()` should be safer...

Comment: I see. Thanks Julien